# Getting "EC2-Classic Networking enabled" in AWS console still

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting the following message in AWS console:

```
"This account has EC2-Classic Networking enabled for one or more AWS regions."
```

I also see this:

[image]

I checked and I do have an EC2 that didn't have a VPC Id.  The others show VPC Id.

I have an RDS which has an Id under the VPC property under "Networking".

I checked Elastic IPs, all have "VPC" scope.

I terminated the EC2 that wasn't VPC.

I still see the notice.

I checked the other regions, nothing there. Is there any way to check what other EC-classic networking features might be there? Do I need to also delete the snapshots/AMIs for the classic as well?

side note: I think maybe because also my VPC is not default VPC. But not sure.
[image]

I have only one VPC under the VPC section in AWS.

**UPDATE**: I did the ec2-classic-resource-finder scan and no classic found on us-east-1. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Plz have a look at this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-classic-is-retiring-heres-how-to-prepare/ It also has a script that can check what are the resources running under classic.

Comment: Additionally, you might have to create a support case to disable the ec2 classic

Comment: I'll see if I can run this script on windows

Comment: How do I run a .sh script from AWS CLI? (Using windows) - already set up AWS CLI for CMD.exe

Comment: Do I need to create a new account? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console

As my account supports EC2

Or migrate everything to a new region which is supported platform only VPC?

Comment: The script doesn't work on Windows, I checked. As you need linux components for it to work.

Comment: I ran the script, I see no classic on us-east-1. Am I required to have a default VPC for tha region?

Comment: You can actually launch the instance (Linux-based) and run the script there. Yes if default VPC is not created then you can create it. Once you are sure there are no components on a classic you can disable that by raising a support ticket. Here the link to create default VPC https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc

Comment: Thanks you @HarshalBulsara I did just that. I contacted AWS they created a new VPC. Do I need now to create snapshots/AMI and relaunch my servers into the new VPC so I can remove the non-default VPC as I need only one?

Comment: Yes, that should do. Additionally, you can request AWS to disable classic on your account that way no one else can create anything inside it.